# Can't Connect to Server via IntegrationServices

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ssis

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server to run a SSIS package.  I admit that this is the first time I've tried this, so I'm not exactly confident that I have everything correct.

I get a generic error of "Failed to connect to server BSQL_01" on the line:

```
IntegrationServices ssisServer = new IntegrationServices(ssisConnection);
```

Here is my SQL Server, and the only package there is the one I'm trying to run:

[image]

Here is the code I'm having issues with.

```
// Connection to the database server where the packages are located
SqlConnection ssisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BSQL_01;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

// SSIS server object with connection
IntegrationServices ssisServer = new IntegrationServices(ssisConnection);

// The reference to the package which you want to execute
PackageInfo ssisPackage = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Folders["PORGImport"].Projects["PORGImport"].Packages["PORGImport.dtsx"];

long executionIdentifier = ssisPackage.Execute(false, null, executionParameter);

ExecutionOperation executionOperation = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Executions[executionIdentifier];

while (!executionOperation.Completed) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    executionOperation.Refresh();
}

if (executionOperation.Status == Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
    MessageBox.Show("Success");

} else if (executionOperation.Status == Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Failed) {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
    MessageBox.Show("Failed");

} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Something Went Really Wrong");
    MessageBox.Show("Oh Crap");
}
```

**Update**

Ok, I changed the Initial Catalog in my ConnectionString to 'Mmaster' and I no longer get the error.  It APPEARS to run as I get the "Success", however, when I check the tables that are supposed to be populated, nothing is there.

Comment: What version of SQL Server, and are you manually connecting using windows authentication?

Comment: Server 2012, using Windows Authentication.  The connection string I use for my SQL Queries works fine, "Data Source=BSQL_01;Initial Catalog=DCI17;Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

Comment: OK. It's not a very helpful error message. Does this help to get more details? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mwories/2009/06/08/powershell-tips-tricks-getting-more-detailed-error-information-from-powershell/ Also a great test would be to just connect to the SQL Server directly. You might get a better error. https://www.sqlshack.com/connecting-powershell-to-sql-server/

Comment: Got it to connect by altering the ConnectionString, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Altered it to what? What line does it get to when you debug it?

Comment: You've got a `while (!executionOperation.Completed)` there - maybe it's just executing. Check in SSMS and see if it is executing

Comment: You should right click on the package and check logs and see if it ran

Comment: @Nick McDermaid I changed the Initial Catalog to master (I added a note to the end of the question).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, it loops while it's running, but then it goes down to if (executionOperation.Status == Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Success) and gives me a 'Success'.

Comment: I checked the messages in the package, and I see this "Purchase File Loop: Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty.  The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty."  Doesn't make any sense as it works fine when I run it via command line or in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is your SQL server on a different machine or the same machine?

Comment: @Dizzy49 instead of writing a note at the end of the question you have to write this as an answer since the you have posted a new question for the new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Initial Catalog" of the ConnectionString needed to be "master", not "SSISDB"

```
SqlConnection ssisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BSQL_01;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```